# Python: how to turn string into a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading from a file and have the following string

> my_item = ['maria' , 'jose']

How can I turn this into a list with two items, i.e.

> my_list = [maria, jose]

Comment: What have you tried? Please be sure to read the About for StackOverflow, and the guide to asking good questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask | http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: Can you show the code that produces this string? It's likely that you already have exactly what you want, but you're misinterpreting your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand your question correctly, looks like you already have a list my_item, which is a list of two strings, string1 - 'maria' and string2 - 'jose'.

If you mean the complete string is something looks like: """my_item = ['maria','jose']"""
Then you do something like this below:

```
inputString = "my_item = ['maria','jose']"

# value is a list type 
value = eval(inputString.split("=")[1])
# key is a string type
key = inputString.split("=")[0].strip()

# I don't think you can define a variable name while the script is running. 
# but you can use dictionary type to call it.
mydict = {}
mydict[key] = value
```

Then you can call mydict[key] to pick up the value which you want to lookup.

```
>>> print mydict['my_item'] 
['maria', 'jose']
```

Comment: Sorry, I totally misphrased the question.  What I am interested is not a dictionary item.  Let me rephrase: I have a string ['maria','jose']after reading from file.txt.  Now I need to turn that string into a list of items.  How can I do that?  Thanks.

Comment: eval() function would take a string and evaluate that into python command. In this case would solve your question.  Say, text="['maria', 'jose']", eval(text) would be what you want